# Using sum as the column size in the dp solution of the coin change problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

The usual way to solve the coin change problem (Count the number of ways we can form a sum using a set of coins) is to take the size of the array as the number of columns and the sum as the number of rows in the tabulation method. But I've been told that using the inverse way, ie, making number of columns equal to sum and number of rows equal to the size of the array doesn't work. I've tried the code out and it gives the right answer. Was the person who said this wrong or am I implementing it wrong?

Here is the code

```
    void coinChange_3(vector<int> arr, int sum) {
        int n=arr.size();
        vector<vector<int>> dp(n+1, vector<int>(sum+1));
        for(int i=0; i<=n; i++) dp[i][0]=1;
        for(int i=1; i<=sum; i++) dp[0][i]=0;
        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            for(int j=1; j<=sum; j++) {
                dp[i][j]=dp[i-1][j];
                if(j>=arr[i-1]) dp[i][j]+=dp[i][j-arr[i-1]];
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<=n; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<=sum; j++) {
                cout<<dp[i][j]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }
```

```
coinChange_3({1, 2, 3}, 4);

1 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 2 2 3 
1 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: what you can do with a 2d array you can also do with the transposed 2d array. Its unclear why this shouldnt work

Comment: I was told this by an instructor in a course for data structures. I am confused as well.

Answer (score 0):

Consider you wrap the 2d array in a class that provides the necessary interface:

```
 struct my_2d_int_array {
        my_2d_array(size_t rows,size_t cols);
        void set(size_t i,size_t j,int value);
        int get(size_t i,size_t j) const;
     private:
        /*...*/
 };
```

From outside there is no way to tell if the data is stored in row major or column major order (other than perhaps measuring the time needed to access adjacent elements along rows/columns). If the implementation internally swaps row major order with column major order, code that uses the `my_2d_int_array` will still work correctly. q.e.d.

You either misunderstood something or someone was telling you non-sense. You should ask the person for clarification.

PS: a vector grants you direct access to the elements. You can for example do pointer arithmetics with pointers to elements in the vector. Doing this depends on the memory layout and can break if the memory layout would change. But you are not doing this in your code. The above interface (which does not grant you direct access to the elements) is sufficient to be used in your code.